# Disable selectableItemBackgroundBorderless On Hold

Tags: android, android-cardview, rippledrawable

I have a `ImageButton` inside a `CardView`, when I press and hold the `CardView` it gets an dark overlay. If inside the `CardView` there are any items with an `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` background, they will get the same hold effect and will show on top of the `CardView`, even if the touch wasn't on them.

Example:

Normal: [image: Normal CardView]

`CardView` pressed: [image: Pressed CardView]

**How do I prevent items with the `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` of showing up when they weren't touched?**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:duplicateParentState="false"` on the `ImageButton`.

Alternatively, if clicking the `>` icon has the same effect as clicking the `CardView`, consider using a regular, non-clickable `ImageView` instead of an `ImageButton`.